# An unexpected error occurred: "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read"

Tags: reactjs, directory, console

I have been trying to create react app using the npx command but every time I run it, I get the error message in console:

```
yarn add v1.22.4
error An unexpected error occurred: "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read".
```

I also get a yarn-error.log file with the first few lines as thus:

```js
Arguments:
  /Users/sammyebinne / .nvm / versions / node / v14 .5 .0 / bin / node / usr / local / Cellar / yarn / 1.22 .4 / libexec / bin / yarn.js add--exact react react - dom react - scripts cra - template--cwd / Users / sammyebinne / Documents / Work / Practice / radler / rad

PATH: /Users/sammyebinne / .npm / _npx / 5326 / bin: /Users/sammyebinne / node_modules / .bin: /Users/sammyebinne / .nvm / versions / node / v14 .5 .0 / bin: /usr/local / bin: /usr/bin: /bin:/usr / sbin: /sbin:~/.npm - global / bin: /Library/Apple / usr / bin: /Users/sammyebinne / .nvm / versions / node / v14 .5 .0 / bin
```

Comment: when use create-react-app and finished . you `cd` for example to `my-app` where project name.and `yarn start`